# Android 'hidden nav (client)'

Tags: android, robotium, android-4.2-jelly-bean

The first click/touch on my app is not working. In the logcat I can see

```
I/InputQueue-JNI(  178): Sending finished signal for input channel 'hidden nav (client)' since it is being unregistered while an input message is still in progress.
I/InputQueue-JNI(  178): Ignoring finish signal on channel that is no longer registered.
```

After this all touches/clicks works perfectly. I am using Jelly Bean and the app is fullscreen with windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"

Can anyone help me on this?